# Using syscall 9 with linked list in MIPS

Tags: mips, system-calls, mars-simulator

I'm trying to implement a linked list in MIPS and I also need to allocate memory for it. In every example I see, they assume that the first element in the list is on certain register, but they don't actually explain how to do it realistically.

I tried this, but it says "store address not aligned on word boundary 0x10040319"

```
# Allocate memory with syscall 9
li $v0, 9
addi $a0, $zero, 8  # Reserve 8 bytes, 4 for int data, 4 for pointer to next
syscall
# Make $t0 point to the beginning of the reserved memory?
add $t0, $v0, $zero
# Create linked list node
addi $t1, $zero, 10   # $t1 has the int data
sw $t1, 0($t0)      # $t1 is now node->data
sw $zero, 4($t0)      # node->next is NULL
```

So I have two questions here, but they are related to each other. One is how to properly allocate memory with syscall 9, and the other one is how to reference it so it can be used in a linked list (I actually need to implement a sorting algorithm using linked lists, because I need to be able to sort any number of elements (not a fixed number) and this is step -1 haha). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh god, apparently it was the simulator they uploaded for the assignment.
I downloaded the most recent version of Mars MIPS from the official website and it worked. Well, this is awkward.